# How to read user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, user-input

I'm writing a program that asks the user how they are feeling, and gives different responses depending on what the user types in. For example, if you were happy or in a good mood it would print on the screen "Glad to hear". However, I don't know how to read user input. What should I try? (Text inside the ** is what I need help with). Thanks!

---

```
`name = input('what is your name?')
print('hello '+ name)
you = input('how are you doing today?')
**if you = happy, good, ok:
print('Glad to hear!')
else:
    print('I am sorry, I think I can cheer you up.')**
game = input('wanna play hangman?')    
print('yay! Ill start it up.')
print('hangman starting up...')`
```

After this a game of hangman starts up.

Comment: It looks like you DO know how to read the user input, because this code _is already using_ the `input()` function.

Comment: Did you want someting like this?
`if ["happy", "good", "ok"] in you:
    print("Glad to hear")`

Comment: @RajeshM you have that backwards.  `if you in ["happy", "good", "ok"]:`

Answer (score 1):

`if you in ['good','great','awesome']` is one way i guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is a string comparison:

```
name = input('what is your name?')
print('hello '+ name)
you = input('how are you doing today?')
# ok, we need to compare the input stored in "you"
# first way is to try expected things, and we can lower case it to facilitate.
if you.lower() == 'good' or you.lower() == 'great':
    print('Glad to hear!')
# ... rest of the code
```

Alternatively:

```
if you.lower() in ['good', 'great', 'awesome']:
    print('Glad to hear!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
name = input('what is your name?')
print('hello '+ name)
you = input('how are you doing today?')
if you == 'happy' or you == 'good' or you == 'ok':
print('Glad to hear!')
else:
    print('I am sorry, I think I can cheer you up.')
game = input('wanna play hangman?')    
print('yay! Ill start it up.')
print('hangman starting up...')
```